# facebook registration plug-in Async Validation

Tags: facebook, validation, plugins, asynchronous, registration

I am trying to impliment facebook registration pluging from last three weeks, to check the username avaiablity I am using jquery and JSON, accourding to this  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/advanced/  guide,  with the following code I am able to send username to my server that is a  a c# page to check either it is available or not, but how to tell back? 
Problem is this I don’t know how to send message from c# page to the calling scritp, and how to use read it here.

```
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=134552926621797&xfbml=1"></script>

<fb:registration redirect-uri="http://dev2.urecommendme.com/test3.aspx" 
  fields='[{"name":"name"},
           {"name":"username","description":"Username","type":"text"}]' 
  onvalidate="validate_async"></fb:registration> 

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function validate_async(form, cb) {
        $.getJSON('http://dev2.urecommendme.com/test01.aspx?username=' + form.username + '&callback=?',
    function (response) {
        if (response.error) {
            // Username isn't taken, let the form submit
           cb();
        }
        alert(cb.toString());

    });
    }
</script> 
</body>
```

Returning message should be something like this

```
<script src="http://graph.facebook.com/shahidgfdgd?callback=jsonp1307613510850">
jsonp1307613510850({
"error": {
"type": "OAuthException",
"message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: shahid"
}
});
</script>
```

This is my third week to implimenting it please guide me so I can complete this task, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FB registration page should look like as follows

```
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=134552926621785&xfbml=1"></script>

<fb:registration redirect-uri="http://dev2.urecommendme.com/test3.aspx" 
  fields='[{"name":"name"},
           {"name":"username","description":"Username","type":"text"}]' 
  onvalidate="validate_async"></fb:registration> 

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function validate_async(form, cb) {
        $.getJSON('test02.aspx?username=' + form.username,
    function (response) {
        if (response.error) {
            // Username isn't taken, let the form submit
            cb();
        }
        cb({ username: 'That username is taken' });
    });
    }
</script> 

</body>
```

Note how I mentioned server file name (it is without full URL, as both files were on same root dir) in validate_async(form, cb) function

```
        $.getJSON('test02.aspx?username=' + form.username,
```

Test02.aspx page should look like as follows

Note no html, body or head tags in test02.aspx
(Test02.aspx.cs) should look like

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text;

public partial class test02 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e1)
    {
        StringBuilder JSON = new StringBuilder();

        //validate from your database and execute one of the following two lines.

       JSON.Append("{\"error\":\"Exist\"}"); // username is taken

     //  JSON.Append("{\"anything\":\"Not Exist\"}");


        Response.Write(JSON.ToString());

        Response.End(); 

    }
}
```