# Facebook registration async username validation

Tags: php, asp.net, facebook, validation, registration

First of I have searched everywhere for an answer and have not come across one so forgive me if I missed something somewhere!

I'm trying to check if a username exists before the Facebook registration form is submitted.
It also seems like the registration can continue even though the validation hasn't been completed! Is there a way to stop the form from submitting before all validation is complete?

A lot of answers link to a post that apparently solves this but the part that is actually important is missing. The post with this answer is [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293923/facebook-registration-plug-in-async-validation).

The contents of "Test02.aspx" is missing which is where I'm stuck.

The facebook part:

```
<fb:registration 
    redirect-uri="read.php/tools/echo" 
    fields="[{'name':'name'},{'name':'email'},{'name':'username','description':'Username','type':'text'},{'name':'password'}]" 
    onvalidate="validate_async">
</fb:registration> 

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script> 
function validate_async(form, cb) {
  $.getJSON('test02.aspx?username=' + form.username + '?callback=?', 
    function(response) {
      if (response.error) {
        // Username isn't taken, let the form submit
        cb();
      }
      cb({username: 'That username is taken'});
  });
}
</script>
```

What I don't know is what to put in test02.aspx. I would prefer to use php to check the database but I can't figure it out!

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you in advance.
Mishka

**--Update--**

*Some changes to client side:*

```
<script>
    function validate(form, cb) {
        $.getJSON('PHP/fb_check_user.php?username=' + form.username,
            function(data){
                $.each(data,function(name,error){
                    if (error === 'true')
                    {
                        cb({username: 'That username is taken'});
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cb();
                    }
                });
            }
        );
    };
</script>
```

To get it to work i had to change this line:

```
$.getJSON('PHP/fb_check_user.php?username=' + form.username + '?callback=?',
```

to:

```
$.getJSON('PHP/fb_check_user.php?username=' + form.username,
```

*Server side:* (fb_check_user.php)

```
<?php

//Connect to database

$user=$_GET['username'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT usr FROM members WHERE usr = '$user'");

if (!mysql_num_rows($query))
{
    $result = array('error' => 'false');
}
else
{
    $result = array('error' => 'true');
}

echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please look at the docs for async validation, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/advanced/#async

Basically, you have your client-side validation function returning null (or no return statement at all) – and then you evaluate the response of your server-side script in the callback function.

How you do that, is up to you.

Possible best, if your server-side script returns JSON, and gives an error value if something went wrong. And then you evaluate that JSON data object in your client-side callback function.

Comment: Thanks for your help @CBroe I've looked at the documentation a couple times but it doesn't really help with what to put in the linked file. I hate asking someone to write code but if you wouldn't mind that would be very helpful! If you don't want to that's fine!

Comment: Again: Write in there (or rather: have it _put out_) whatever you like – whatever helps you decide in your callback function if there was an error or not.

Comment: I don't know how to fulfil the response.error if statement from php. This is the first time I've even heard about JSON so I'm not sure about the syntax or requirements to communicate between JavaScript and php.

Comment: Put this into your PHP script: `echo json_encode(array('error' => 'foo'));` And then, in your client-side callback function, log the response object to your browser’s console via `console.log(response)`

Comment: Thanks I nearly have it working now. The problem I'm having now is that even if the "Username is taken" message is displayed I'm still able to submit the form?

Comment: What exactly is your server-side script returning, and how is your callback function reacting on that? (Please update your question with code samples.)

Comment: I'm just going to assume I'm not getting more responses.